# Loop in a multidimensional array and its subarray with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've the following array:

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Item 1',
        'desc' => 'Lorem ipsum...',
        'rates' => array(
            'Yes' => 50,
            'No' => 75
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Item 2',
        'desc' => 'Lorem ipsum...',
        'rates' => array(
            'Yes' => 50,
            'No' => 0
        )
    )
);
```

How can I loop between the `rates` ?

Here what I tried:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    foreach($item['rates'] as $rate => $value){
        echo $rate['rates'];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first variable is always the key, so you can't use it as an array. In your second loop, you're already looping through the values of `rates`, so `$rate` would be Yes/No, and $value would be the value associated with that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  foreach($item['rates'] as $rate => $value){
    echo $value;echo '<br/>';
 }
}
```

in second loop `$rate` is key and `$value` have the current value of that key.

Answer (score 1):

**To keep (and continue) your work:**

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  echo "Number of ratings for item: {$item['name']}<br/>";
  foreach($item['rates'] as $rateKey => $rateValue) {
    echo " - {$rateKey}: {$rateValue}<br/>";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Number of ratings for item: Item 1
- Yes: 50
- No: 75
Number of ratings for item: Item 2
- Yes: 50
- No: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    foreach($item['rates'] as $rate => $value){
        echo 'Rate is ' . $rate . '; value is ' . $value . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, code only answers are generally regarded as lo-quality. Providing some more description and context on why will improve the quality of this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Loop within loop is way slower than looping and it would only become noticeable when array that you're looping gets bigger. So one approach you could take is given below:

```
    $items = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Item 1',
        'desc' => 'Lorem ipsum text',
        'rates' => array(
            'Yes' => 50,
            'No' => 75
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Item 2',
        'desc' => 'Lorem ipsum text',
        'rates' => array(
            'Yes' => 50,
            'No' => 0
        )
     )
    );

$rates = array_column($items, 'rates');

foreach($rates as $key => $value) {
    if($value['Yes']) {
         echo " Yes: {$value['Yes']}<br/>";
    }
     echo " No: {$value['No']}<br/><br/>";
}
```

Result:

```
Yes: 50
No: 75

Yes: 50
No: 0
```